# Transfer file path to another class and add items to a list

Tags: python, class, pyqt5

I have a menubar in the mainwindow class which I want to use to select a file directory. Once the file directory is selected it should call a function in the ui class to load the filenames into the list box. The filepath is being sent to the other function but the list doesn't load any items. My code is below thanks in advance.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import os

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.ui_widget = ui(parent=self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui_widget)
        # filling up a menu bar
        bar = self.menuBar()
        # File menu
        file_menu = bar.addMenu('File')
        # adding actions to file menu
        images_dir = QtWidgets.QAction('Set Images Dir', self)
        close_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Close', self)
        file_menu.addAction(images_dir)

        # use `connect` method to bind signals to desired behavior
        close_action.triggered.connect(self.close)
        images_dir.triggered.connect(self.set_images_dir)

    def set_images_dir(self):
        filepath = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Select Directory")
        if filepath:
            filepath=filepath+'/'
            ui().image_dir_select(filepath)
            self.image_dir=filepath
        return          

class ui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.listwidget = QListWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)

    def image_dir_select(self, image_dir):

        filelist=os.listdir(image_dir)
        self.listwidget.clear()
        filelist=list(set(filelist))
        filelist.sort()
        self.listwidget.addItems(filelist)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = MainWindow()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `image_dir_select` of the existing ui_widget, but you're doing it against a new instance.

Change this:

```
    ui().image_dir_select(filepath)
```

To this:

```
    self.ui_widget.image_dir_select(filepath)
```